# woocommerce: product variables drop down isn't showing in my theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a product to my store that is available in different colours.

I’m hoping that the customer would choose the colour from a drop down, select the quantity required, and then add it to their cart.

I have added it correctly in the back-end, and even linked the colours up to their respective SKU’s.

The drop down for the colours simply isn’t showing up on the front-end.

I tested it on the storefront theme, and it shows up and works just fine through that – so I’m led to believe that my custom theme is at fault.

What code would I need to conditionally show up a drop down if a product has variations?

This is a snippet of my current content-single-product.php page, where I assume this code would live:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input-group spinner">

<input type="text" class="form-control" step="1" min="1" max="253" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty">

<div class="input-group-btn-vertical">
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
</div>

</div>

<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>">
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-cart">Add to cart</button>
```

The page I need help with: https://www.bagnboxman.co.uk/product/teststtsts/

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like the normal woocommerce code for content-single-product.php There are no woocommerce hooks so the variations won't load.

If you want to recode this completely, take a look at

```
plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php
```

You will find the template code there.

I recommend to rethink your template as it´s much easier to work with hooks like.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

Comment: This is my full content-single-product.php file: https://gist.github.com/Tjobbe/5e035b231b30f41608f00962cb823d99

Comment: This file is where the magic happens: [link on github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php) there is no check for variable products in your file. You did not include any of the needed code for variable products so the variations won´t show.